# Create Shortcut of our own application

Tags: android, google-play

I have just downloaded an application from the android market. When I have installed the application, at the same a time shortcut of that application has been created on the default desktop.

So, my question is: how can we create a shortcut of our application at the time of installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen).

Give that one a try, it also creates an icon on the home screen, but not during installation. Of course you could make it so it creates this icon during the first run of the app if you want.

The icon being created during the installation is something the user can set in their options, it's not something you have influence on, so you'll have to use an option like above.

Answer (score 2):

That's an option in the Android System settings for the end user. User can choose to have shortcuts created automatically. That's not something you can do as a developer.

Comment: I must add that neither is it something you SHOULD do.

Comment: What I have written Please Read Care fully. If the application which is downloaded from android market can create shortcut at the time of installation then definitely we can do. It is just matter of finding solution.

Comment: There is no definitely about it. Its the operating system - Android itself, not the application creating the shortcut. There are a lot of things you cannot do on Android programatically, even changing the time for example. There are frequently reasons why the folks who designed android want to prevent things from happening.

Comment: But If one Application(if it is not inbuilt) do then other application also can do.