# How To Create Shortcut Automatically After Installation?

Tags: android, shortcut

How To Create Shortcut Automatically After Installation? Code Below Does't Work!

```
 private void createShortCut() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_SHORTCUT);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
     intent.putExtra("duplicate", false); 
     Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);//icon
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class));

     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     sendBroadcast(intent);
 }
```

Comment: did you check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create shortcuts automatically after installation, because nothing of your code runs automatically after installation.

Comment: Is it possible after the first launch?

Comment: Then what you say about apps on Google play store,they creates shortcut automatically

Comment: @JayVyas: The Play Store app installer is doing that, not the app being installed.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please tell me the way to implement to create shortcut icon from play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible to create shortcut be it your app or any third party app or system apps. Please follow this sample code.

```
  try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < packageNameArray.length; i++)
            {
                Intent shortcutIntent = Util.makeIntent(MyPreference.getAction(context), MyPreference.getCategory(context), packageNameArray[i], ActivityNameArray[i]);
                Bitmap shortcutIcon2 = Util.confleteBitmap((UtilityClass.StringToBitMap(IconArray[i])), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.shortcut_mark));
                data.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT", shortcutIntent);
                data.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON", shortcutIcon2);
                data.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME", AppNameArray[i]);
                //uninstalling shortcut to remove duplicacy
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
                intent.putExtras(data);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here **packagenamearray** is all apps you select to create shortcut you pass you app **package name** here if you have just your app shortcut to be created
**activitynamearray** is **activityname** of selected app.