# Shortcut of your app in to home, automatically

Tags: android, android-launcher

How can I create **automatically**, once installed, a shortcut for my app in the home of the launcher in use?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/) page which has a tutorial on how to accomplish this. But mind you, this is undocumented, and might not work on all devices. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337645/473637) answer to a related question on SO. I also believe that since Android 4.0, the os automatically does this for newly installed apps if it could find enough space for a short cut on a home screen.

Comment: A small addition to your answer. Since 4.0, the OS will add a shortcut automatically only if the option to add shortcut automatically is checked in Google Play.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Thanks, I wasn't aware that it was optional.

Comment: No problem. Glad to add some info. :-)