# Android App closes after creating shortcut icon on homescreen

Tags: android, icons, shortcut

I'm having problem when I tried to create the shortcut icon in the homescreen of the Android App programmatically.

I was able to create the shortcut icon but after that, an alert stating "application shortcut created" pops up then the application closes. I don't want the application to close and if possible I want to get rid of the alert that pops up after creating the shortcut.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my current code:

```
Intent targetIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
targetIntent.setClassName (getApplicationContext(), "com.mainListActivity");
Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
shortcutintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

//repeat to create is forbidden
shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

//set the name of shortCut
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"SecureLauncher");

//set icon
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_cloud);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);

//set the application to lunch when you click the icon
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,targetIntent);
sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen

Comment: yes i did and it still closes the application after creating the app

Comment: so when you say closes, all the activity lifecycle methods are called?

Comment: nope,none of them are called, only the oncreate function where i placed the code, then afterwards, it closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the the cause why the application closes it is in my manifest.xml

before i have this in my manifest: i removed the receiver part:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<receiver
    android:name=".CreateShortcut"
    android:permission="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

so i only have this in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code when create short cut**

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginScreen.class);     
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "AIMS DOCTOR");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),    R.drawable.aims));
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Also you should use this on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```