# Collectible Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently I'm scanning the web for information about widgets, which can be collected in folders on Android 4 und further, but I did not have any success yet.
What I found where a lot of tutorials for creating standard widgets.

I also have read about shortcuts, but wasn't successful in finding any useful information, either.

Examples of what I'm looking are the "Direct Message" or "Direct Call" widgets of android itself, the "Google Drive" Shortcuts, the "ID Now" of Soundhound, and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen) and Android (I guess since Android 3 or 4) will show your shortcut as Widget in the widget section of the stock launcher.