# Creating a shortcut of an android application on Home screen

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen)

I want to create a shortcut of my android application on home screen as soon as my application is installed in an android device. How do I do this..?

Comment: @Ram,I want to create a shortcut as soon as application installs on device.I want create it before opening my application for the first time. I don't want to create it on a button click.

Answer (score 3):

as Answer by @Kailash :

You can use below code it worked for me:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("WRITE YOUR PACKAGE NAME", "WRITE HERE YOUR CLASS NAME");

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "WRITE HERE YOUR SHORTCUT NAME");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

You have to use following **permission in your AndroidManaifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: not working....