# How do I read the label text from the shortcut that invoked my Android App?

Tags: java, android, shortcut

Can I read the label text from the application **shortcut** that invoked my Android program?

I can read the application name:

```
getString(R.string.app_name)
```

but that's not what i want.  It needs to be the custom label text that is assigned to the shortcut.

I plan to have multiple shortcuts with different labels.  The label will influence some behaviour of my program.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to know the name or text of the shortcut you made, instead you can use that shortcut to "pass arguments" to the activity via an intent. Your shortcut will be a regular Activity, it will just pass an argument to the main Activity of your application using an Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("some_tag", true);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the Activity to be launched,

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent in) {
    super.onNewIntent(in);

    if(in.hasExtra("some_tag") && in.getExtra("some_tag") == true) {
        //Do Something Special
    }
}
```

Note that you need `launchMode` set to `singleTop` to use `onNewIntent()` as noted here:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

More information can be found here:

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/11444-add-shortcuts-your-android-application.html

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for posting. I'll be able to work with the method you have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

No, the launching shortcut's label is not passed to you in any manner.