# Creating a login type of activity and forcing it the only opening point

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have been doing my research, but I feel as if I am missing something.

I have an app with a login. Each time you open the app, you should be forced through that login page. You should never be able to resume onto any activity other than the login.

In the manifest I have

```
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

on the main activity I wish to use as the login activity,

and

```
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

as well as

```
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

on the rest of the activities.

The problamatic situation occurs when you go from the login to another activity, hit home, and relaunch the app via the icon. It should jump back to the login page, but it doesnt. Any idea?

I have also been installing as a regular apk, not via eclipse as I know that there is an issue with eclipse and some of the manifest attributes.

Perhaps if there is a way to detect that the activity launch came from the app icon press, I could manage it that way, but I dont think that is possible either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either `onResume` or `onRestart` you could check a series of flags, such as a login timeout, then force the user back to the login activity using an `Intent`, while at the same time finishing the original activity.

I like this method in favor or just finishing the app in either `onPause` or `onStop` because it gives you a chance to make some checks before blindly closing the application.

Or, you could try using the `android:noHistory` tag in your manifest file.

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

There are also other tags such as, `android:finishOnTaskLaunch`

> Whether or not an existing instance of the activity should be shut down (finished) whenever the user again launches its task (chooses the task on the home screen) — "true" if it should be shut down, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: would there be a way to detect f the intent came from pressing the app icon? thats the only point that im having trouble protecting right now. EVERY time you open via the icon, regardless of whether you logged in 5 seconds ago or 5 days ago, it should force you to do it agian.

Comment: Yes, you can use an Intent to `putExtra` data in the Intent to start the activity, which can be used as a sort of  "argument" using `hasExtra` in the activity that is being resumed. In this way you can check to see where the activity was started from. For example, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370888/how-do-i-read-the-label-text-from-the-shortcut-that-invoked-my-android-app/17371339#17371339

Comment: im not able to put any extras if it comes from the launcher. Basically, your suggestiong adding extras to all my intents and checking that its there, and if its not, restart the main activity. that seems like a ton of work. there has got to be a better built in way to manage something as simple as this.

Comment: Yeah, my original solution would work, but is really only viable with a small-scale application. Try using either the `android:noHistory` or the `android:finishOnTaskLaunch` in your manifest.

Comment: This is not good for me either. With noHistory, if u hit back, it jumps directly to the launcher.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onBackPressed` in conjunction with `noHistory`? Other than that, the manifest documentation doesn't mention anything about forcing an activity on resume. Perhaps try using `android:stateNotNeeded`, it may be that Android is preventing your application from utilizing `android:finishOnTaskLaunch` because it's trying to save the state.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32837/discussion-between-david-freitag-and-r2doesinc)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way is probably to terminate the activity with finish(); in its onPause() since this is invoked when the App is put into the background.

It might be possible to solve with XML configuration as well, but not that I know of by heart.

Comment: im trying to avoid doing it in the code as it generally leads to unfamiliar activity stack behavior. im attempting to do it via manifest configuration because i would hope that that would keep it as uniform as possible.