# Adding app launch icon to the home screen

Tags: android, icons, launcher

I would like to place the app launch icon on the home screen once the user installs my android app. This should be done even if the user does not open the app. 
I have tried adding "category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"  in the manifest file for my main activity. But this does not work. 
Any pointers on how solve this issue?

Thanks
Srao

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be enough:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```