# Is there an the official workaround for lack of `android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT` on certain android phones?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to generate a shortcut using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337645/391161).

However, I noticed that my Galaxy S4 does not have a button for adding a shortcut to the home screen (when I long-tap, the only options are "Set Wallpaper", "Apps and Widgets" and "Folder".

Thus, there seems to be no GUI way to invoke `android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT`. I can do it from `adb` manually using `adb`, but that will not feasible for non-developer users.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT
```

Is there a different Intent I can listen for instead to work around this problem and create shortcuts anyways?

Answer (score 0):

`"android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"` is the [official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) and the correct intent. You should be using it.

As for the S4, create shortcut could be bundled within the widgets category.

Comment: Based on my testing, my app does not appear in the widgets category. However, it does appear when I use the command line to generate that Intent.

Comment: Hmm.. probably, you could add a menu option to trigger that intent from your apps UI? Additionally, make the intent explicit to get rid of "Complete action with..." dialog.

Comment: If I make the intent explicit, then it seems that returning the actual shortcut as an Intent will no longer work? Since CREAT_SHORTCUT is a special action that the system expects to return a shortcut.

Comment: Right. Since you'd be the one installing the shortcut, you will have to add [`"com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_SHORTCUT) permission.