# Add HomeScreen WebApps from another application?

Tags: android

With Chrome you can add HomeScreen Web Apps pressing `Add to home screen` from menu. I would like to make an app that generates HomeScreen Web Apps by passign an URL.

[image: Chrome for Android]

Is it possible to add HomeScreen Web App from another application different from Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look at [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut).

Comment: A question in the above link contains a technique that is not recommended. Look  [another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen) for details.

Comment: @matt FYI A question with bounty cannot be closed as duplicate. I've flagged it for moderation attention, but received no response. Thank you for resolving this issue.

Comment: @naXa: Ah, I didn't notice it was you who flagged it (it was your flag that brought this question to my attention).