# IBM worklight application how to make as app short-cut by default on user mobile home screen after app installation

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I have implemented the IBM worklight 6.1 hybrid application and deployed the .apk and .ipa on ibm app center and .wlpp .adpater files on worklight console.
my requirements is when user downloads the the .apk or .ipa file from IBM app centre and once app get installed on mobile then  installed app short-cut should create by default on home screen of user mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an application auto-downloaded from App Center and into the user device. The user must login to the AppCenter client app and select to download the app.

Comment: ya  user already  installed the app centre and he has downloaded the android app from app centre when he will install the app then by default app short-cut should be create on user mobile home screen. instead manually creating the app short-cut. for example like  if i install the flipkart app in my mobile from google play store then flipkart app short-cut by default get created on my mobile home screen.like wise is there any similer feature in worklight.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen