# How to add more than one Homepage shortcut for android app with different functionality

Tags: android, homescreen

I am trying to build an Android Application which contains more than one functionality and I want these functionalities to be accesses with one click from home menu in Android.
ex. First (shortcut-icon) sends predefined SMS on user click.
Second icon sends predefined email .
Third and forth etc ...
What I know is: it can be achieved through `Widgets`. But I need it from icons not only widgets is there a way to avoid making multi apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create multiple `Activities` with unique functionality each. Then list them all in manifest like

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.SmsActivity"
    android:label="Send SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and so on for each app's feature. You should end up with a single application having multiple "entry points".

Comment: Will it add all the activities as icons on home screen ?

Comment: It will add them to All Apps screen. User will be able to move them manually.

Comment: btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen