# Create shortcut in home screen on publishing android app in mobile

Tags: android

I am developing one android app its almost developed and I am able to successfully publish it in my mobile and its working fine, but its not creating a shortcut in home screen after install, can somebody please help me how to create shortcut after install.

Comment: It's a system feature. Well, it's actually a setting in the Play Store app.

Comment: hey Lonnie, I have not published in store I am testing it locally with my mobile.

Comment: Thats what @LonnieZamora is trying to tell you. You only get a shortcut on your home screen after installing an app from the play store, not during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I found (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23893035/2507782) because in this we are checking if shortcut already exist and along with this some modifications in manifest files are.

```
<activity android:name=".ShortCutActivity" android:label="@string/shortcut_label">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:naenter code hereme="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```