# does google play automatically creates shortcut of our app on home screen?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm about to launch my first app in a week,and want to know if google play automatically adds the shortcut to the home-screen or is it something if have to do with code. I have question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen) but there's nothing about creating shortcut on install.

Comment: The shortcut is automatically added.

Comment: if the shortcut is automatically added.why some users are giving the below answers?

Comment: thank you @konrad-krakowiak yeah the shortcut is automatically added by   google play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I launched my app found that Google Play does automatically creates a shortcut on the homescreen and we don't have to do it in our code,although i don't know if it works the same way in Amazon app store. hope this helps someone who is trying to find answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Mohit Madaan's answer was correct. Just don't forget to set duplicate to false otherwise you might have several shortcuts:

```
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

below for creating the shortcut icon on android Homescreen

```
private void ShortcutIcon(){

Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Test");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and I hope this helps you. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcut-example/