# Make a simple txt-file in an easy to access dir on the phone?

Tags: android

I am trying out how to save data on the phone. The problem is that I can't seem to find any of the files that i'm making because they are in directories that is impossible to access on my phone.

Is it possible to make a txt-file in an easy to access directory, like the myfiles/documents directory?

If this is possible, what is the typical file path to "my files/documents" on the phone?

Comment: Please show your code... *I can't seem to find any of the files that i'm making*... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage

Comment: did you consider using shared preferences, is it in app or external>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android saving file to external storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

Comment: There is no typical path because phones aren't all the same. `Documents` exists on my SD card, though, so again, please show some code you've tried

Comment: the only line of code in question would be:File file = new File(path to directory, "myfile.txt");

Comment: [%100 works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen).  ;D