# Android shortcut issue

Tags: android, shortcut, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

I am creating a Shortcut icon with the following code which is working on my device.

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AlertActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ss");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.sss));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so   don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Now I am trying to upload my application to the play store for some of the devices this icon is not creating.

Note: I am facing this issue with Nexus 6, Android 7.1.1. What could be the issue here

Here this code is working even with the signed apk.

Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: have you assigned permission `<uses-permission
       android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />` ??

Comment: Yes I have added this permission

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919589/create-shortcuts-in-home-screen-android) is not the answer but try to read, it might help.

Comment: What is the difference between my code and that answer

Comment: he has used a boolean there to differentiate multiple shortcuts created or not... and as I mentioned in first sentence it might not be the answer but might help you figure out something..

Comment: That's for avoiding the duplicate shortcut.