# Android Dev | Create quick shortcut

Tags: java, android, shortcut

I would that my users can add a **shortcut**, selecting it in the widget list.
I searched in Google but I don't found anything.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen), but I don't want to create a shortcut with this method.
I add also an image: I don't intend an 1x1 widget, but a shortcut, like *Browser Bookmark*.
[image: Widget]

Comment: Ask the developer of Nova Launcher how you get Nova Launcher to offer that option for your app.

Comment: But there are shortcuts also in other launcher or app. I think that it is an Android feature.

Comment: I fail to see how that stops you from asking the developer of Nova Launcher how you get Nova Launcher to offer that option for your app. It is possible that this is part of their backport of static app shortcuts (introduced in Android 7.1), but the only way to know is to ask them.

Comment: Perhaps they are [App Widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)