# Creating shortcuts in Android via Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, homescreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android create shortcuts on the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen)

I am having one `TextView` and `Button` in my Activity (HomeActivity.class).

**Goal**: When I click on the `Button` it should create a shortcut with the default android image as icon and text as entered in the `TextView`.

So far I've found out that we can create shortcuts using [`ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)

This is the code I have so far:

```
Intent result = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Editor.class));
result.putExtra(TodoDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,rowid);
result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,textView.getText());
result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(HomeActivity.this,
                                                        R.drawable.icon));
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
```

My Manifest File :

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But this code does not create any shortcut.

How can I create shortcuts?

Comment: I think you should have a look at [this page](http://codinggeek.org/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/). It's also possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676090/android-is-there-a-programming-way-to-create-a-web-shortcut-on-home-screen) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent shortcutIntent;
shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(activity.getPackageName(), ".classname"));

shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

final Intent putShortCutIntent = new Intent();
putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);

// Sets the custom shortcut's title
putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"Title");
putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(PersonProfile.this, R.drawable.icon));
putShortCutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(putShortCutIntent);
```

and add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Does this still work ?

Comment: @CapDroid: This creates a shortcut even if there exists one. Can we create the shortcut in a way that it replaces the existing one instead of duplicating..? Please guide.

Comment: @CapDroid: Isn't this just for the stock launcher? Or any launcher set as default by the user?

Comment: This won't work on Android 8.0 and above. Instead you need to use this:   `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/pm/ShortcutManagerCompat.html#requestPinShortcut(android.content.Context, android.support.v4.content.pm.ShortcutInfoCompat, android.content.IntentSender)`