# Create shortcut for other applications but wrong size icon on Android Jellybean

Tags: android, icons, size, shortcut

I have an `activity` that can retrieve all applications that just like Launcher `AllAppsList` (or I should call them activities precisely, since an application can have multiple `activities`, like Google map). And this `activity` can broadcast an `Intent` to create shortcuts for any of these application. And my problem is about the shortcut created. Here is my code create shortcut:

```
public static void addShortcut(Context c, ActivityInfo actInfo){
    PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager() ;
    String packageName = actInfo.packageName ;
    String className = actInfo.name ;
    CharSequence label = actInfo.loadLabel(pm) ;

    // Create an Intent to launch the application
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN) ;
    shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, className)) ;
    shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) ;
    // Create an Intent to notify Launcher to create a shortcut on home screen
    Intent addIntent = new Intent() ;
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent) ;
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, label) ;
    // Put in the shortcut's icon
    Log.i(TAG, "use actInfo.loadIcon(pm)") ;
    Drawable drawable = actInfo.loadIcon(pm) ;
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, b) ;

    // Broadcast the Intent
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    c.sendBroadcast(addIntent) ;
}
```

This can successfully create a shortcut on home screen, but those icons' size are almost not correct. They could be too small or too large. [Like this image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UrZ4.jpg) The upper row is 2 shortcuts I created. The 2 shortcuts below are dragged from Launcher's `AllAppsView` and they are normal. Apparently mine are smaller...

The first thing I've tried is resizing the icons. But if I do so, the icon created would not be as perfect as those I drag from Launcher's AllAppsView. In other words, they became vague.

Another try is this code:

```
 if (actInfo.icon != 0){
        Log.i(TAG, "use actInfo.icon") ;
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(c, actInfo.icon)) ;
    }
    else if (actInfo.applicationInfo.icon != 0){
        Log.i(TAG, "use actInfo.applicationInfo.icon") ;
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(c, actInfo.applicationInfo.icon)) ;
    }
```

[which is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424246/creating-shortcuts-in-android-via-intent), but this cannot work either.

Wish somebody can give me a hand:)

Comment: @Avadhani Thanks for improving the format:)

Answer (score 0):

what i think you should do is :

```
final int appIconSize=(int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density*48);
final Bitmap temp;
if(shortcutIconBitmap.getWidth()==appIconSize&&shortcutIconBitmap.getHeight()==appIconSize)
    temp=shortcutIconBitmap;
else temp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(shortcutIconBitmap,appIconSize,appIconSize,true);
putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON,temp);
```

if you have the app run on API 11 and above only, you can use [getLauncherLargeIconSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLauncherLargeIconSize%28%29) instead, but i haven't used it much, so i can only say that for galaxy s3, both methods return the same value (96).